# The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it. Error in Django

Tags: python, django

```
The included URLconf '<module 'myapp.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\Python\\Django Projects\\myproject\\myapp\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

This is the error that I am getting while building my django app.

Here is urls.py from myapp -

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Here is views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey, Welcome</h1>')
```

this is from urls.py from myproject-

```
"""myproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to edit your view file like the following :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

#this is new 
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey, Welcome</h1>')
```